# No scrollbar when screen content expands in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, scrollbar, scrollview

I'm creating an android app that stores some data in the database. The main activity screen has a couple of EditTexts. There is also a multiline EditText which expands depending on the text that is written in it. Now, whenever the textbox expands, the screen size stays the same, there is now way to scroll down. No scrollbar is shown.

Here is my xml layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="be.example.timelogger.NewLogActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/dateText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStartTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/startTimeText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEndTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvStartTime"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputStartTime"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="@string/endTimeText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDurationTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inputEndTime"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/durationTimeText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputDate"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvDuration"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputEndTime"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvEndTime"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvEndTime"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inputDate"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:onClick="showTimePickerDialogEnd" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputStartTime"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inputEndTime"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvStartTime"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:onClick="showTimePickerDialogStart" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDuration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvEndTime"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/durationText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCourse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvDuration"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDuration"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/tvCourseText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinCourse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvCourse"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvDurationTime" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtComment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvComment"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/inputEndTime"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvComment"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvComment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCourse"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinCourse"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/commentText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtComment"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/btnSaveText" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: in your xml code, you started with <b>ScrollView</b> which is never closed anywhere in the code. Try to close that, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

The RelativeLayout inside your ScrollView should have height `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll View should be closed at the end
 .

Comment: The scrollview is closed in my xml file, I just forgot to paste the last line (which contained the closing tag) in the post